# How to send data from a form to a email

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, mailto

I want to send the data colected from a form to my email, i tried using the "mailto" function, but i was looking for a way to automatically send the data, without the need for the user to open his email.
I used this script trying to do that, but it didn't work the way i wanted, it still open'd the mail "box". The code i used for trying this, is this:

```
function getCookie(name){
    var cname=name + "=";
    var dc=document.cookie;
    if (dc.length > 0){
        begin=dc.indexOf(cname);
        if (begin != -1){
            begin += cname.length;
            end=dc.indexOf(";", begin);
            if (end == -1) end=dc.length;
            return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
 
function setCookie(name, value){
    var now=new Date();
    var then=new Date(now.getTime() + 31536000000);
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; expires=" + then.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
}
 
function getInfo(form){
    form.info.value="Browser Information: " + navigator.userAgent;
}
 
function getValue(element){
    var value=getCookie(element.name);
    if (value != null) element.value=value;
}
 
function setValue(element){
    setCookie(element.name, element.value);
}
 
function fixElement(element, message){
    alert(message);
    element.focus();
}
 
function isMailReady(form){
    var passed=false;
    if (form.fullname.value == ""){
    fixElement(form.fullname, "coloque seu nome.");
    }
    else if (form.email.value.indexOf("@") == -1 || form.email.value.indexOf(".") == -1){
        fixElement(form.email, "coloque um e-mail válido.");
    }
    else if (form.message.value == ""){
        fixElement(form.message, "coloque uma mensagem.");
    }
    else{
        getInfo(form);
        passed=true;
    }
    return passed;
}
```

Comment: You should try something yourself first. What have you tried so far? You could do a bit of your own research for this.

Comment: i did, i used a script that i got here actually, but it does the same thing, when you click submit, it opens the mail "box"

Comment: What script did use?

Comment: i just edited the answer, sorry

Comment: Send the form data to your server and have the server send the mail. There are many questions on [so] about this.

Comment: You should be using PHP for mailing. Or if your hoster has a mailing service, use that.

Comment: JavaScript can't send mail itself. Either you use the user's mail program though `mailto:` or you send to a server script that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to utilize HTML & PHP instead of JavaScript and rename your form page to `form.php`. Thereafter, try something like this in the `form.php` file:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="your@email.address";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact form to email</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?=$thankYou ?>

    <form method="post" action="form.php">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input name="sender">

        <label>Email address:</label>
        <input name="senderEmail">

        <label>Message:</label>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="message"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

A `mailto:` link indicates the email address of the intended recipient and when clicked, opens a new outgoing email message with a visitor's default mail client.

Above, we've added a sender name and sender email address to the message and also included a confirmation message to inform the sender know their message has been successfully sent.

Additionally, we check the form has been sent by looking for the form field named "submit". If it has, we:

1. Set pertinent variables:

   a. Your email address

   b. The email subject

   c. The sender’s name (taken from the form)

   d. The sender’s email address (taken from the form)

   e. The message (taken from the form)
2. Send the email, using all of the above variables
3. Set a variable for a confirmation message
4. Load the HTML, including the confirmation message

If the page loads and no form data has been sent, then no email will be composed and no conformation message will be displayed.

Be certain to update the value of "your@email.address" to the intended destination email.

See more about the code above in this [Form to Email](https://www.htmldog.com/techniques/formtoemail/) post.

Comment: thank you so much man, this really helped me!! thanks for being such a nice person